# 404 error while redirecting the request from servlet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In-spite of reading many post regarding 404 error i could not figure out my mistake while re-directing the request. I know 404 is mainly due to wrong path provided by us, but still i am unable to fix the issue.

I want to send request to **FirstJSP.jsp** which is located in **/ReportFetcher/WebContent**
from my servlet **SubmitMarksController** which is in **/ReportFetcher/JavaResource/src/** and in src it is located in package **com.gaurav.controller**

Below is list of property of request reference that has value corresponding to their name:

1. Context path  = "/ReportFetcher"
2. Request dispatcher path = "/SubmitMarksController"
3. Request URI = "/ReportFetcher/SubmitMarksController"
4. Servlet path = "/SubmitMarksController"

My attempt is following:

```
response.sendRedirect("/ReportFetcher/WebContent/FirstJSP.jsp");
return ;
```

Comment: What url do you see when you get `404` ?

Comment: URL : http://localhost:8080/ReportFetcher/WebContent/FirstJSP.jsp and  description : The requested resource (/ReportFetcher/WebContent/FirstJSP.jsp) is not available

Comment: Try accessing your jsp with this url : localhost:8080/ReportFetcher/FirstJSP.jsp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try response.sendRedirect("FirstJSP.jsp");
WebContent is the root of any web application. So all the paths are relative to it.

Comment: Thanks it works for me. but could  you please give me brief information why my code was not working. Since "/" was root for all the components then "/ReportFetcher/WebContent/FirstJSP.jsp" should be ok according to my understanding. Please correct me if i am missing something

Comment: first please let me know if you are using eclipse?

Comment: Yes i am using eclipse Version: 3.7.2

Comment: Then go into this path inside your eclipse workspace .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps. Here you will see all the web applications deployed by you through eclipse. You can see the complete folder hierarchy for your web application. Your application name is the root(WebContent renamed into your application name) . Compiled classes goes inside WEB-INF/classes and anything placed inside WebCOntent goed directly under the ROOT. You can explore a bit practically though which will give a clear idea.

Comment: I found my web app project's folder with one more folder called ROOT.

Comment: ROOT is a default by eclipse which you can override by copying ROOT from Apache Tomcats default. Its hit when you simply hit http://localhost. If you replace the ROOT you can get any web app by hitting http://localhost